# Extract XML value by searching for other value

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm certain I'm getting something simple wrong with the syntax, but I've tried several different iterations and variations. Can't quite get there!

The XML data I'm working with looks like this:

```
<HybridSchedule>
    <matchNumber>1</matchNumber>
    <scoreBlueFinal>260</scoreBlueFinal>
    <scoreRedFinal>135</scoreRedFinal>
    <startTime>2017-03-25T10:30:00</startTime>
    <Teams>
        <Team>
            <station>Red1</station>
            <teamNumber>6514</teamNumber>
        </Team>
        <Team>
            <station>Red2</station>
            <teamNumber>1285</teamNumber>
        </Team>
    </Teams>
</HybridSchedule>
```

What I'm trying to do is extract **teamNumber** based on the value of **station**

What I've tried, among many other variations is:

```
$red1res = $HybridSchedule->xpath("//Teams/Team/station[.='Red1']/parent::*");
$red1 = $red1res[0]->teamNumber;
```

The code above returns blank, and I've tried a dozen variations based on code I found on different sites, but I'm clearly missing something. The value of $red1 should be 6514, based on the sample data provided.

Based on feedback provided so far, here's the new code with the larger context:

```
foreach ($xml->Schedule->children() as $HybridSchedule) {

        // Collect the data for the table
        $match = $HybridSchedule->matchNumber;
        $schedelements = explode("T", $HybridSchedule->startTime);
        $schedtime = substr($schedelements[1], 0, 5);
        $scorebluefinal = $HybridSchedule->scoreBlueFinal;
        $scoreredfinal = $HybridSchedule->scoreRedFinal;
        $Teams = $HybridSchedule->Teams;

        $blue1res = $Teams->xpath("/Team[station='Blue1']/teamNumber/text()");
        $blue1 = $blue1res[0];
}
```

The xpath is now working, but the array is showing all of the entries from $xml not just the entry from $HybridSchedule.

Comment: Have you considered using SimpleXML? There are more resources in terms of information available and it is officially supported by PHP.

Comment: It seems the issue I'm running into is that I'm trying to mix SimpleXML with xpath. The XML sample above is a subset of a larger data pool. I have extracted $HybridSchedule using foreach ($xml->Schedule->children() as $HybridSchedule) and I failed to recognize that this was an object, not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign the result from the Xpath into `$red1res` but read the value from `$blue1res` - these are two different variables.

Anyway, your Xpath can be simplified if you look at it a slightly different way:

1. any `Team` child element in any child element `Teams`...
   `Teams/Team`
2. that has a `station` with the text content `Red1`...
   `Teams/Team[station='Red1']`
3. its `teamNumber` child ...
   `Teams/Team[station='Red1']/teamNumber`

Filter conditions in `[]` can be complex. This way the only the matching `Team` is returned so here is no need to go back up.

Starting an expression with `/` means that it will be in the context of the document, two `//` mean that you fetch any descendant. If you just start with the tag name it looks at the child nodes. To get descendants while still using the context you have to use `.//` (`.` represents the current node and avoids starting the location path with a `/`.)

Additionally Xpath allows type casts but this will only work with `DOMXpath::evaluate()`. (Not with `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()`.)

4. cast the result into a string
   `string(Teams/Team[station='Red1']/teamNumber)`

You already know how do use Xpath with SimpleXML, so here is a DOM example:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$schedule = $document->documentElement; 

var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate('string(Teams/Team[station="Red1"]/teamNumber)', $schedule)
);
```

Output:

```
string(4) "6514"
```

A difference between `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` and `DOMXpath::evaluate()` is that a `SimpleXMLElement` represents an element node and this element node is used as the context for the expression. `DOMXpath` instances are only connected to the document, so you will have to provide the context as an argument to the method call.

Comment: Thank you. This is the solution to my xpath problem. I have, however run into a new issue in that since HybridSchedule is an element of a larger XML structure, it is returning all HybridSchedule entries where station=Red1, not just the one from the current Hybrid Schedule. Will update my code above to reflect that.

Comment: I modified it to take context into account.

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath is almost there...

```
//Teams/Team/station[.='Red1']/parent::*/teamNumber/text()
```

Sometimes it's a case of trying it out, I use something like http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath which allows you to tune the XPath till you get the information your after.

Answer (score -1):

I would use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) instead. In my opinion, it's a cleaner API and as @Jesse pointed out, it's officially supported.

```
// If you have the XML as a string in a variable
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);

// If you prefer the OOP style
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);

// If you're loading it from a file
$xml = simplexml_load_file('/path/to/file');

$teamNumber = null;

foreach ($xml->Teams->Team as $team) {
    if ($team->station == 'Red1') {
        // We need to cast it as an int, or we're going to end up
        // with a "SimpleXMLElement"-object.
        $teamNumber = (int) $team->teamNumber;

        // We found our item, let's stop iterating
        break;
    }
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/dt2Tr